# Running wg-quick up wg0 is altering my /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf file

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, vps, wireguard

Im using debian 11 server on my VPS, and trying to setup wireguard.

after creating my private and public keys, i create my config file **/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf** with contents

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = [PRV_KEY]
Address = 192.168.23.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
SaveConfig = true

[peer]
PublicKey = [PUB_KEY]
AllowedIPs = 192.168.23.2
```

Calling **wg-quick up wg0**

```
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 192.168.23.1/24 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
```

**ip addr** shows the new wg0 interface

Now my **/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf** has been altered to

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.23.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = [PRV_KEY]
```

the **[peer]** block is completely missing.

As I am new to wireguard and VPNS, im assuming without this peer block being parsed, I dont have a public key...

Comment: save config is your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SaveConfig = true

> SaveConfig — if set to `true', the configuration is saved from the current state of the interface upon shutdown. Any changes made to the configuration file before the interface is removed will therefore be overwritten.

Taken from [`man wg-quick`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/wireguard-tools/wg-quick.8.en.html). Remove that line.